# Visualizing dispersion of textual data

Tags: r, for-loop, visualization

I'm trying to visualize how text data are distributed across positions in sentences. Here's some mock data:

```
# create mock data:
dfmock <- data.frame(letter = c(sample(letters[1:3], 25, replace = T)),
                 position = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5), rep(5, 5))
                 )
```

For the plot I first create a dummy frame:

```
# create dummy data frame for plot:
dummytest <-data.frame(slots = 1:5, rows = 1:5)
```

and then plot the outlines of the dummy frame:

```
# plot:
plot(dummytest$rows ~ dummytest$slots, type="n", frame=F, axes=F)
axis(1, at=seq(1:5), labels=unique(dfmock$position))
```

Now I'd like to highlight occurrences of, say, the item "a"; to do so, I define a loop and use the text() function to highlight "a" using a red solid line and printing everything else grey:

```
# print "a" in positions:
for(i in unique(dfmock$position)){
text(i, 1:5, "___", cex=1.75,
   col = ifelse(dfmock[dfmock$letter=="a",]$position==i, "red", "grey"))
}
```

While a plot is being produced, the wrong number of highlights are shown per position. I can't just figure out why this is. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% of the output you desire, but guessing from the above this might fix it:

**Using your code setup dummy data frames**

```
# create mock data:
dfmock <- data.frame(letter = c(sample(letters[1:3], 25, replace = T)),
                     position = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5), rep(5, 5))
) 

# create dummy data frame for plot:
dummytest <-data.frame(slots = 1:5, rows = 1:5)
```

**Again Plot the Data**

```
# plot:
plot(dummytest$rows ~ dummytest$slots, type="n", frame=F, axes=F)
axis(1, at=seq(1:5), labels=unique(dfmock$position))
```

> The FIX:

It seems your FOR loop was iterating over the wrong data and thus your `ifelse` was returning a logical vector that was not always of the same dimension as your plot data.

```
# print "a" in positions:
for(i in dfmock$position){
  text(i, dummytest$rows, "___", cex=1.75,
       col = ifelse(dfmock[dfmock$position==i,]$letter=="a", "red", "grey"))
}
```

This produced the below PLOT for a dfmock as per below:

```
> dfmock[dfmock$letter=="a",]
   letter position
4       a        1
8       a        2
12      a        3
13      a        3
14      a        3
21      a        5
25      a        5
```

[image]